# PrimeFaces FileUpload: how many files are selected?

Tags: file-upload, primefaces

The "multiple files" feature enables to select more files for uploading. The listener is called after each transmission. But I don't know how many files will be uploaded by the component at all.

I would like to navigate to the next page after all the selected files were processed. Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

```
fileUploadListener="#{uploadBean.handleFileUpload}"
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe not a good solution but you can use the oncomplete from p:fileUpload to trigger a hidden button, which invokes a action to navigate.

```
<p:fileUpload ... oncomplete="$('#btn').click()" />
```

and

```
<p:commandButton id="btn" action="#{myBean.actionToNavigate}" style="display:none;" />
```